# I want to write bitmap image file with what I have already rendered through OpenGL

Tags: opengl, file-io, bitmap

I'm trying to write bitmap files for every frames that I rendered through OpenGL.

Please notice that I'm not going to read bitmap, I'm gonna WRITE NEW BITMAP files.

Here is part of my C++ code

```
void COpenGLWnd::ShowinWnd(int ID)
{
    if(m_isitStart == 1)
    {
        m_hDC = ::GetDC(m_hWnd);
        SetDCPixelFormat(m_hDC);

         m_hRC = wglCreateContext(m_hDC);
        VERIFY(wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC));
         m_isitStart = 0;
    }

    GLRender();

    CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(m_hDC);
    //pDC->FillSolidRect(0, 0, 100, 100, RGB(100, 100, 100));
    CRect rcClient;
    GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    SaveBitmapToDirectFile(pDC, rcClient, _T("a.bmp"));

    SwapBuffers(m_hDC);
}
```

"GLRender" is the function which can render on the MFC window.
"SaveBitmapToDirectFile" is the function that writes a new bitmap image file from the parameter pDC, and I could check that it works well if I erase that double slash on the second line, because only gray box on left top is drawn at "a.bmp"

So where has m_hDC gone? I have no idea why rendered scene wasn't written on "a.bmp".

Here is GLRender codes, but I don't think that this function was the problem, because it can render image and print it out well on window.

```
void COpenGLWnd::GLFadeinRender()
{
    glViewport(0,0, m_WndWidth, m_WndHeight);
    glOrtho(0, m_WndWidth, 0, m_WndHeight, 0, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glBlendFunc(m_BlendingSrc, m_BlendingDest);

    glPixelTransferf(GL_ALPHA_SCALE,(GLfloat)(1-m_BlendingAlpha));

    glPixelZoom((GLfloat)m_WndWidth/(GLfloat)m_w1, -(GLfloat)m_WndHeight/(GLfloat)m_h1);    

    glRasterPos2f(0, m_WndHeight);                                          
    glDrawPixels((GLsizei)m_w1, (GLsizei)m_h1, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pImageA);

    glPixelTransferf(GL_ALPHA_SCALE,(GLfloat)m_BlendingAlpha);                  
    glPixelZoom((GLfloat)m_WndWidth/(GLfloat)m_w2, -(GLfloat)m_WndHeight/(GLfloat)m_h2);    

    glRasterPos2f(0, m_WndHeight);                              
    glDrawPixels((GLsizei)m_w2, (GLsizei)m_h2, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pImageB);    

    glFlush();  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using MFC or Windows API functions to capture the bitmap from the window.  The problem is that you need to use glReadPixels to get the image from a GL context -- winapi isn't able to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still I don't know how to use it. Did you mean that I need to use glReadPixels on pDC? Nothing has changed when I used it after glDrawPixels on my "a.bmp".

Comment: Nope, glReadPixels is an OpenGL call, so it operates on the currently active context just like all the other OpenGL calls.  Google for "glReadPixels example" or something like that, you'll find plenty of code showing you how to use it :)